# Manually migrate MonoTouch project for XCode 4 using MonoDevelop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, migrate

I just upgraded to the latest MonoDevelop (2.8) and upon opening MonoDevelop, it asked to migrate my MonoTouch project to allow it to use XCode 4 with MonoDevelop 2.8.

According to the dialog I was presented with, the process was irreversible so I just closed the dialog while I went to backup and read up more about the project migration process.

When I went back to actually migrate the project, I can't find anywhere in MonoDevelop to force the migration process (re-opening the project does not prompt me with the migration as it did the first time).

Anyone know a way to manually perform this migration in MonoDevelop?

Cheers.

Comment: If a project hasn't been migrated, you should be asked every time you open that project. Are you sure the project didn't inadvertedly get upgraded?

Comment: I just tested your theory and you are correct. I guess if you click to close the dialog it is migrated anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"According to the dialog I was presented with, the process was irreversible so I just closed the dialog while I went to backup and read up more about the project migration process."

You could have always just clicked on 'Backup and Upgrade' which will perform a backup of all necessary files for you. If something dire should happen during the upgrade process, it's a simple case of copying the files back out of the backup directory and you'll be back to the way things were. This should be 100% safe.

Alan.

EDIT: I've also just fixed that bug. There was an if/else statement which defaulted to BackupAndMigrate if none of the valid options were hit, this was a bit silly in hindsight, it should've defaulted to DoNotMigrate. Your original project files were put in a directory called 'backup' in your project folder so you can easily undo the accidental migration :)